# How to solve CSS dropdown border error?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, dropdown

```css
.dropdown {
  border: 5px solid;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffcccc;
}
.dropdown-content {
  border: 5px solid;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff9cc;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span> <code> relative; </code> </span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <span> <code> absolute; <code> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above snippet, the `.dropdown-content` is **not right** below the `.dropdown` because the **border size** is adding the difference.

If we remove the  `border` . The `.dropdown-content` comes **right** below the `.dropdown`.

How can one use border and show it right below each other.

How this CSS `border` error can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `left: -5px` to compensate for the 5px border as in the below:

```css
.dropdown {
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropdown-content {
  border: 5px solid;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff9cc;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: -5px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span> <code> relative; </code> </span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <span> <code> absolute; <code> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to wait 10 minutes I believe ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to add negative `margin` in this way.Here is the perfect solution for you.Just add the `border-top: 5px solid;` and remove `position:absolute` from `.dropdown-content` class.Hope this will ok.Thanks.

```css
.dropdown {
  border: 5px solid;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffcccc;
}
.dropdown-content {
  border-top: 5px solid;
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff9cc;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span> <code> relative; </code> </span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <span> <code> absolute; <code> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add **margin-left:-5px** to **.dropdown-content**

```css
.dropdown {
  border: 5px solid;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffcccc;
}
.dropdown-content {
  border: 5px solid;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff9cc;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-left:-5px;


}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span> <code> relative; </code> </span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <span> <code> absolute; <code> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
margin-left: -5px;
```

or

```
left: -5px;
```

the padding moves the cursor to the right

Answer (score 1):

If you go with bellow link and use that code it will be resolve your problem. and this is semantically good approch.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h